# How to use a custom composable as parameter type in another custom composable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, composable

Is there a way to use a custom composable as a parameter type in another custom composable? Trying this only throws an `unresolved reference` compiler error. However, using build-in composables provided by Jetpack Compose as parameters like an `AlertDialog` don't throw any errors. I want to use the slots API pattern in a custom composable but restrict the slots to  only other custom composables.

**Example structure**

```
@Composable
fun Permission(
    PermissionNotGrantedContent: CustomDialog, //Unresolved reference error here
    PermissionNotAvailableContent: CustomDialog, //unresolved reference error here
    PermissionGrantedContent: @Composable () -> Unit
) { ... }

Permission(
    PermissionNotGrantedContent = {
        CustomDialog(...)           
    },
    PermissionNotAvailableContent = { 
        CustomDialog(...)
    }
) {
    Text("Thanks for granting the permission!")
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your sample code?

Comment: @Rafsanjani It throws an `Unresolved reference` error for `CustomDialog`.

Comment: And are you sure your `CustomDialog` is available within scope? I don't see any reason why `CustomDialog` will be unresolved unless you've declared it as private within a different file

Comment: `CustomDialog` is from another library of mine, but it's not declared private. And I even tested this with a public composable created in the same file, and it still throws `Unresolved reference` error. That error occurs in the `Permission` declaration site shown above. But, `CustomDialog` works outside of the parameter scope.  And even if I use a built-in composable, which doesn't throw that error, like `AlertDialog`, I still can't get it to work at the `Permission` call site. I can't use a lamda nor use it straight as it throws errors. I'm at a loss as to how to implement this in my code.

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix this problem?

Comment: @ShadeToD Not yet. I'm hoping someone will come along with a solution.

Comment: Checkout how `RowScope` is used in `Row` for example (you can look at others as well like `Column`). `rowContent: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit` This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but it may get you headed in the right direction. However, I don't think this is directly possible as methods don't have types (reflection notwithstanding).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is how compose uses scoping interfaces. For that checkout the source for `RowScope` and `RowScopeInstance` and how it is used in `Row`. I'm not sure how "compose-y" this is, but you can do something more or less concrete like this:

```
interface CustomDialog {
  @Composable
  fun Content()
}

class PermissionNotGrantedContent(
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  /* other data needed */
) : CustomDialog {
  @Composable
  override fun Content() {
    /* draw the dialog */
  }
}

@Composable
fun Permission(
  notgranted: CustomDialog,
  /* etc. */
) {
  notgranted.Content()
  /* etc. */
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewPermissions() {
  Permission(
     notgranted = PermissionNotGranted(/* params */)
  )
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

For exemple TextField use :

```
trailingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null
```

And I do that :

```
trailingIcon = {
    IconButton(onClick = { viewModel.changeVisibility() }) {
        if (viewModel.clearPassword.collectAsState().value!!) {
            Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_visibility), contentDescription = "visible icon")
        } else {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_invisible), contentDescription = "invisible icon")
        }
    }
},
```

You should use command + left click(Probably CTRL + left click on Window) on a composable fonction like Box, TextField, it can show you lot of parameters and you can see how it works.